# php pdo double quotes also getting escaped

Tags: php, pdo

I am using php pdo->quote to before injecting values into database. but surprisingly double quotes (") are also getting escaped! tried disabling magic_quotes_gpc, magic_quotes_runtime, magic_quotes_sybase in php.ini .htaccess and also by ini_set. still out of luck. the double quotes are getting escaped along with the single quotes. 
It's not only adding slashes while inserting values to database, even a simple echo $pdo->quotes('hi "this" is a test'); is giving me 'hi \"this\" is a test' as output. I dont want to escape the double quotes! Is there any workaround without switching to prepared statements? I avoided prepared statements because of many issues I was facing!

I am sure that i haven't used addslashes anywhere. is there any work around to fix this issue? im using xampp 1.8.2. Kindly help. Thanks!

Comment: Try using prepared statements instead, as mentioned on this page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php

Comment: is there any workaround without switching to prepared statements? i avoided prepared statements because of many issues I was facing!

Comment: Not that I can tell, from looking at the quote page.

Comment: What issues you were facing?

Comment: Using prepared statements is worth whatever learning curve you might have starting to use them.  Without them, you are leaving yourself open to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

> giving me `'hi \"this\" is a test'` as output.

that's correct output. There is absolutely nothing wrong with it. You shouldn't worry of these slashes at all.

> I dont want to escape the double quotes!

You do. At least as long as you are using this function.

Anyway, you should use **prepared statements** instead.

Comment: see i dont think there is any need to add slashes to double quotes before inserting data to database right?

Comment: :) thanks anyway! out of my curiosity "are double quotes harmful while inserting data to database?"

Comment: Do you have any reason to think so?

Comment: i thought only single quotes are harmful! my mistake! thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: Neither quotes are "harmful". there are some characters that have to be escaped in string literals, not limited to quotes. That's just formatting rules